# A way to hid a div when another div is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have two `divs` that are set to hidden until the button is clicked the only problem is that I don't want both of them to show at the same time.

```
<div id="SearchAddParams" class="hidden" style="color:orangered">
    <label for='txtSearch'>Street Number:</label>
    <input type='text' id='txtStreetNum' />
    <label for='txtSearch'>PreDir:</label>
    <input type='text' id='txtPreDir' />
    <label for='txtSearch'>PreType:</label>
    <input type='text' id='txtPreType' />
    <label for='txtSearch'>Street Name:</label>
    <input type='text' id='txtStreetName' />
    <label for='txtSearch'>Suf Dir</label>
    <input type='text' id='txtSufDir' />
    <input type='button' id='btnSearch' onclick='searchAddress()' value='Search' />
    <input type='button' id='reset' onclick='resetbutton()' value='Reset' />
</div>
<div id="SearchParParams" class="hidden" style="color:orangered">
    <label for='txtSearch'>Parcel ID:</label>
    <input type='text' id='txtParcelID' />
    <label for='txtSearch'>Owner:</label>
    <input type='text' id='txtOwner' />
    <label for='txtSearch'>Owner Addr:</label>
    <input type='text' id='txtOwnerAddr' />
    <label for='txtSearch'>Quick RefID:</label>
    <input type='text' id='txtQuickRefID' />
    <label for='txtSearch'>Section Township:</label>
    <input type='text' id='txtSectTwn' />
    <input type='button' id='btnSearch2' onclick='searchParcels()' value='Search' />
    <input type='button' id='reset2' onclick='resetbutton2()' value='Reset' />
</div>
```

The code I'm using to hid these divs is

```
function unhide (divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
        item.className = (item.className == 'hidden') ? 'unhidden' : 'hidden';
    }
}
```

is there any way to hid one div when the other is clicked cause i keep getting both of the divs open at once! [Two `divs` showing at the same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TC1Q.png)

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a common class to the divs that are toggleable and use that class to hide all but the selected one.

**html**

```
<div id ="SearchAddParams" class="hidden group" style="color:orangered">
...
</div>

<div id="SearchParParams" class="hidden group" style="color:orangered">
...
</div>
```

**javascript (*jquery*)**

```
function unhide(divID) {
    var group= $('.group'),
        target = group.filter('#'+divId);

    if (target.length) {
        group.removeClass('unhidden').addClass('hidden');
        target.addClass('unhidden').removeClass('hidden');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toggle()` method:

```
$('#SearchParParams, #SearchAddParams').toggle();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1tkzdp1s/)**

Comment: Yes. for show hide it will. just make sure that you are keeping single element hidden using css `display:none`.

Answer (score 1):

here is you solution with pure javascript :

```js
function togglediv() {
   var SearchAddParams = document.getElementById('SearchAddParams');
    var SearchParParams = document.getElementById('SearchParParams');
   // SearchAddParams.style.display = "none" ? "block" : "none";
   if(SearchAddParams.style.display == null || SearchAddParams.style.display == "none") {
        SearchAddParams.style.display = "block";
  
    } else {
        SearchAddParams.style.display = "none";
    }
 if(SearchParParams.style.display == null || SearchParParams.style.display == "none") {
        SearchParParams.style.display = "block";
  
    } else {
        SearchParParams.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="togglediv()" >click</button>
<div id="SearchAddParams">SearchAddParams</div>
    <div id="SearchParParams">SearchParParams</div>
```